# How to make update with subquery?

Tags: mysql, subquery

The Query is:

```
update products 
set sort_order = 
(SELECT max(sort_order) from products where branch_id = 1) + 1 
where branch_id = 1
```

all value under sort_order is currently = 0, i want them to increment. 
The error shown is:

> You can't specify target table 'products' for update in FROM clause

table structure is

```
products:

product_id (int auto_increment),

product_category_id (int not unique), 

product_name (varchar), 

sort_order (int to specify which will be shown first sort_order ASC),

status (int 1 for active 0 for inactive), 

branch_id (int not unique)
```

What should be the subquery then?

Comment: Please include your table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Ah, now I get what you want. Try this:

```
set @row_counter := 0;
update products 
set sort_order = @row_counter := @row_counter + 1
where branch_id = 1
order by whatever_column_determines_the_sort_order;
```

Read more about user-defined variables [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html).

---

**Original answer:**

The order of operations usually is

1. FROM clause
2. WHERE clause
3. GROUP BY clause
4. HAVING clause
5. SELECT clause
6. ORDER BY clause

for a `select` query. It's the same for `update`. In an `update` the `set` equals the `select`. The key to success here, is to have the (sub)query to the table you want to update in the `from` clause.

```
update products 
cross join (select max(sort_order) + 1 mso from products where branch_id = 1) sq 
set sort_order = mso 
where branch_id = 1;
```

Test:

```
mysql>  create table products(branch_id int, sort_order int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> insert into products values (1, 0), (2, 0);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> update products cross join (select max(sort_order) + 1 mso from products where branch_id = 1) sq set sort_order = mso where branch_id = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from products;
+-----------+------------+
| branch_id | sort_order |
+-----------+------------+
|         1 |          1 |
|         2 |          0 |
+-----------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: It just made all sort_order = 1.

Comment: Yes, `where branch_id = 1`, that's what you wanted / described with your code. Add whatever you want into your `where` clause.

Comment: @user2530985 I think now I get, what you want. Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: sorry i did not specify, there are possibly hundreds of branch_id = 1. Its not unique. So for every product_id under that branch_id it has a unique sort_order.

Comment: Yes, got that. Try my answer.

Comment: `update products 
cross join (select @row_counter := 0) var_init 
set sort_order = @row_counter := @row_counter + 1
where branch_id = 1
order by product_category_id, product_name`

Comment: Oh, yes, forgot that order by does not work with multiple tables in an update statement. Fixed it, please try again.

Comment: Oh wow,  thank you kind  sir. Need to learn more about this mysql. Never hear of the @ thing.